# python multiprocessing.Queue memory consumption & release

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

I am using a [multiprocessing.Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) in a python application. It bridges two processes which have different cpu intensive jobs. At a peak when the consuming process is slow the queue will grow to around 2.5GB at peak times (though this may only last for an hour). With no CPU growth in the second process the whole application runs happily in ~100MB of Resident Memory.

However as this is a long running process I was wondering is it possible to release the memory that the Queue allocates manually say maybe on an hourly basis?

Comment: How about limiting the queue by the `maxsize` parameter?

Comment: Thanks Janne. I don't particularly wan't to do that I will have other code that more dynamically controls how much gets into the queue. My question relates to once the queue no longer needs to be large can that memory not be reduced. Seems a huge oversight if not.

Comment: Python releases memory automatically, but then there is this thing called [memory fragmentation](http://revista.python.org.ar/2/en/html/memory-fragmentation.html)

Comment: An alternative approach would be for the producer to store the actual data in eg. a database or plain files, and only pass id numbers/file names over the queue. This should keep the memory consumption of the Python processes low.

Comment: You might simply restart the process from time to time, with `os.execv()`, when it is idle and sitting around using too much memory for now.

Comment: Thanks Guys. However it is a long running production process. It runs for 5 working days before it is or can be restarted ideally. Also it needs to be extremely high throughput (i consume 10 billion network events a week a single instance of this app) so putting a DB in the critical path isn't a good idea